# Python Time Arithmetic - removing 3 hours from a python datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I was working on a pandas plot and needed to start the plot from 3 hours earlier than the current time in order to remove the superfluous data prior to 3 hours ago.

I ended up doing it like this:

```
import datetime
todaydate = datetime.datetime.now() # sets todaydate to the current date and time`
tdiff = datetime.timedelta(hours=-3) # sets a time delay object to -3 hours
plotfrom = todaydate + tdiff # adds the datetime object to the timedelta object.

print (plotfrom.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " is three hours earlier than " + todaydate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  )

>>> 2021-07-09 12:58:46 is three hours earlier than 2021-07-09 15:58:46
```

My question is is there a "one-liner" way of doing the same thing without using the diff variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can is simple:

3 hours into the past:
`plotfrom = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)`

3 hours into the future:
`plotfrom = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

plotfrom = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=3)

plotfrom.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use f-strings:

```
import datetime
todaydate = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print(f"{(todaydate-datetime.timedelta(hours=3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')} is three hours earlier than {todaydate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}")
2021-07-09 08:16:23 is three hours earlier than 2021-07-09 11:16:23
```

Answer (score 0):

For stuff like this I like `arrow` since the syntax is really easy to remember.

```
todaydate = arrow.now()
plotform = todaydate.shift(hours=-3)

print(plotfrom.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + " is three hours earlier than " + todaydate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))
```

To get the raw `datetime` object from that, it's just `plotform.datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do math to datetimes inline.

```
import datetime
now_minus_three_hours = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print("Three hours ago from local time is:", now_minus_three_hours)
```

Three hours ago from local time is: 2021-07-09 07:18:16